SQL Server accepting just Date and not Date & Time from witihin VB
I have a strange problem with (just) one of my SQL Server database columns which is declared as datetime. It is a bigger application and I am using lots of tables with datetime columns, and all of them are set correctly (date & time) - except one.
Syntax (eg) is like:
FKMachineMeasureModulesMachineMeasureHistoryBindingSource.Current("LastTested") = Now()

The connection to SQL Server is done via datasets. So I assumed, maybe the column declaration probably was set to date instead of datetime but no, everywhere correct declared.
However, the statement above results in '2024-07-18 00:00:00.000' in the SQL Server table.
If I update the column via SSMS by running
UPDATE [Machine_MeasureModules] 
SET RLastTested = '18.07.2024 15:10' 
WHERE id = 15271

it's set correctly to 2024-07-18 15:10:00.000.
When I debug the line and update within code, the inline variable browser shows it also correct. But on SQL Server, always without time.
I also tried for this specific column a format conversion of Now(), but same result.



table schema and dataset definition required

Seems like your code is applying a string-formatted date instead of an actual DateTime instance, and I'm surprised that date format works half as well as it does. Really you should be sending an actual DateTime instance, but if you must string-formatted values then use the universal format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss (note the T separator) so as to avoid DATEFORMAT settings on the current connection, e.g.: db<>fiddle.

@testing-for-ya: Thats the crux: Now() is used in about hundred other cases in the project with exactly the same syntax and everywhere else, it works as it should. The commit in VB after assigning the value is done by FKMachineMeasureModulesMachineMeasureHistoryBindingSource.EndEdit()                         Machine_MeasureModulesTableAdapter.Update(DataSet_Machine.Machine_MeasureModules) and checked by a breakpoint right after that, the variabel browser/explorer invoked by  shows the correct date and time. But the SELECT .. in the SQL DB via SMSS shows it without time.

@AndrewMorton: Regional settings are set correct as it works well like mentioned above, for hundreds of similar statements

@AlwaysLearning: First, thanks for your effort to help ! The point is, that nowhere in the whole code, a string formatting of Now() is done. Neither on that specific statement.

@Werner Does the VB code use SQL parameters to pass the values? (But don't use AddWithValue as that can cause problems.)

@AndrewMorton No. The dataset acts as the interface for VB by tableadapter and bindingsource. In my example I am updating the bindingsource directly. Again, the same methods and interface I use also verywhere else

Open up the code generated class file for the dataset, and double check what the type used in that dataset. I suspect that the dataset is not being re-generated after you made changes.

@AlbertD.Kallal I did this alread and yes, the DBType declared in the .xsd was set to Date instead of DateTime. Therefore, I manually patched the .xsd and recompiled the project but didn't help. However, in the Datasource manager, I removed the column and right after, added it again. And: miracle happend, the type is set correct now and the column stores and shows date & time. So thanks for pushing me to check on that again. Question solved

To solve the issue, in the Datasource manager, I removed the column and right after, added it again. And: miracle happend, the type is set correct now and the column stores and shows date & time.
